# Is built-in function not pushed in call stack in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, blink

Now I am testing some of javascript features.

When I run some built-in functions implemented in chrome browser ,
these functions are not seen at all in Call Stack on Chrome devTools. For example,

```
function f(){
    console.log('hi')
}
```

I expected the process that f function will be pushed and then console.log method will be pushed on call stack, but in Call Stack presentd in devTools, only f function was pushed. So I wonder why console.log methods are not pushed.

I assume that console.log method was not pushed because that is built-in function. If so, I wonder why built-in function is not pushed on call stack.

Thank you for your understanding that English is not my first language.

Comment: "*in Call Stack presentd in devTools*" - where exactly? On a breakpoint? Probably you didn't set the breakpoint *within* `console.log`, did you?

Comment: I set breakpoint before calling console.log method. when reacing breakpoint, I press F9 for watching next step. but I cannot see console.log in call stack.

Comment: If you step over it, you'll see the call stack after it has been pushed and popped again. You cannot step into the builtin function, so you'll never see `console.log` on the call stack although it certainly is put there when calling it.

Comment: You may have more luck with finding builtin functions on the callstack when using one that takes a callback, e.g. `[1,2].forEach(() => { debugger; })`